# How I center html "ul" element in bootstrap 4 (horizontal + vertical) inside <section><div class='row'><div class='col-sm'>

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, alignment, html-lists, center

How to center html "**ul**" element in bootstrap4 (horizontal + vertical) with horizontal aligned "**li**"

```html
<section>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm'>
            <ul>
                 <li>A</li>
                 <li>B</li>
                 <li>C</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this code the list will be displayed in the center of the yellow box. I don't know why it won't work on the code preview on stackoverflow, but [here](https://blank.mfest.dev/try.html) you can see that it works.

```html
<section>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm' style="background-color: yellow; display:grid;height: 100%">
            <ul style="margin: center;">
                 <li>A</li>
                 <li>B</li>
                 <li>C</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: And how to make the "li" aligned horizontal ? and could you know why your code is not working in code snippet, Please update your answer

Comment: To align <li> horizontally, all you have to do is to add float: left; list-style-type: none; padding-left: 15px; to each li-Tag, you can find an example using the link from my first answer and yes I know why the code isn't working on stackoverflow because margin:auto doesn't work in the code snippet, but I don't know why it wont work in a snippet.

Comment: but I think on your own website everything should work like in my example